# Inheritance issue - passing derived Class to base Class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I need to duplicate functionality in 2 different 'view' classes, with the only difference in functionality determined by a direction (string or bool) and int value.
So, inheritance makes sense to avoid code duplication.

For simplicity sake, in my base class, `Animal`, I have the following event handler and two 2 derived classes, `DogView` and `CatView`.

What is the 'best' way to pass in 'DogView' and 'CatView' to this base class so they are visible by this event handler? (and optionally 'dogPrefab' and 'catPrefab')
I want to avoid overriding this handler since there are other similar event handlers and I would be duplicating the majority of the base class, hence defeating the reason for inheritance in the first place.

```
bool MyEventHandler(IEvent evt)
{
    Event_Enter castEvent = evt as Event_Enter;
    if (castEvent != null)
    {
         Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(0,-1.1f, 0);
         GameObject ob = (GameObject)Instantiate(dogPrefab, newPos, Quaternion.identity);                    
         DogView animal = ob.GetComponent<DogView>();
         animal._id = castEvent.id;                
    }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: So you want to pass class objects into this EventHandler and not an IEvent?

Comment: No, please see my edited post.

Comment: This sounds roughly like a scenario you would use an interface in. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

Comment: IAnimal animal = ob.GetComponent<IAnimal>()   ??

Comment: Yes. Then you can set the prefab as a property in your animal class. For example as a gameobject or as a string, aka the string path to the prefab in your resource folder. Then everything should work fine. Example: Instantiate(animal.prefabResourceString, .. .. ..). If you are not familiar with using the resource folder to locate prefabs programmatically then check it out!

Comment: Heck, you can use `GetComponent` on an `Animal` *class* if you want to keep it functional.